# Image Align In Slider

Tags: image, alignment

Hope someone can help. I am quite an amateur at this sort of stuff and have edited a template site I was sent for a site my friend wanted to set up. I have a slider on one page and landscape images of 744 x 495 fit fine, when I try and add a portrait image on there it automatically aligns to the left and I need it in the middle. Any suggestions? The site is [www.jaymcallister.co.uk](http://www.jaymcallister.co.uk).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your new image should have the same size and you need to add some additonal black "space" on left like here:
http://www.jaymcallister.co.uk/images/01.jpg